# Can white wine vinegar be used instead of white vinegar?

Tags: cake

Recipe calls for white vinegar

Can  I use white wine vinegar diluted to 5 %  acidity?

Comment: Usually wine vinegar has *less* acidity, so diluting would be counter-productive.   What are you making?  Please provide a recipe.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ She probably means it says on the label that it's diluted to 5% acidity. That's commonly seen.

Comment: Yeah, usually that would be OK, what are you making? - Come to think of it I can't think of any application where it wouldn't be OK, but I'd still like to know what you're making before I post it as an answer.

Comment: Agree we need to know the application.  I’m curious about the very specific acidity.  As others have said, there’s a big flavour difference.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, vinegars that aren't central to the application (e.g. Balsamic Vinegar in in a Balsamic Reduction) are interchangeable within the same acidity level. Every kind of vinegar has a different distinct flavor and color, so any substitutions will affect the final dish, but not necessarily negatively. Distilled (regular white) vinegar ranges from 5-8% acidity, is colorless and pretty flavorless. Since white wine vinegar has very little color and is mildly flavored, and your vinegar is 5% acidity, it should be a fine substitution.

Comment: Personally I prefer balsamic or (color) wine vinegars due to taste, but I typically use them in salad dressings where the vinegar is central to the dish.

Answer (score -4):

No, because white vinegar is distilled with water and chemicals. White wine vinegar is a stronger substance and will damage the sterilizer. White vinegar has a strong and sour taste to it, while white wine vinegar is sour and used as a dressing for salads.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid I'm not understanding your answer. What sterilizer?